# LaTeX arrow ) -->

Tags: arrows

I need to make an arrow similar to this `)-->`.  I cannot get the `)` to size with the `->`.  I have tried `{\tiny )}\!\rightarrow and {\small)}\!rightarrow` and the `)` is too large for the arrow.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 16):

Also, Ti*k*Z can be quite useful for this. The `Arc Barb` from the `arrows.meta` library can be used and the size can be easily adjusted. Here is a new command `\barb` for convenience in both text and math modes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\barb}{%
  \tikz{\draw[{Arc Barb[reversed]}-{latex}] (0,0)--(.5,0);}
}

$x\, \barb\, y$

text \barb tetxt

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the most flexible but note that it would not adapt to different math contexts (e.g. subscripts)

Comment: pretty epic, I must say

Answer (score 9):

Maybe `\rightarrowtail` from `amssymb` package will be fine for you. Here is a sample code that works for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$\rightarrowtail$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

What about something like this?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb} 
\newcommand{\myarrow}{\raisebox{.5pt}{$\scriptstyle)$}\mspace{-7mu}\rightarrow}
\begin{document}
\[
\raisebox{.5pt}{$\scriptstyle)$}\mspace{-7mu}\rightarrow
\]
Of course, you can use a new command:
\[
\myarrow
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]